# Searching nested arrays and returning the key from a matching value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
[
    [mile] => [
            [acronym] => mi
    ],
    [kilometer] => [
            [acronym] => km
    ]
]

$acronym = 'km';
```

How may I return the key name from a matching `acronym` value? In this example I want to return `kilometer`.

Comment: Have you tried something to get to your goal yourself ?

Comment: So where are we with this question? Did any of the answers below helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

Here I just simply create an array with [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) where I use the [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) with the keyname `acronym` as keys and the [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) from the `$arr` as values.

```
<?php

    $acronym = "km";
    $arr = array_combine(array_column($arr, "acronym"), array_keys($arr));
    echo $arr[$acronym];

?>
```

output:

```
kilometer
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, only php >5.5 :(

Comment: @splash58 You can easily change out the `array_column($arr, "acronym")` with `array_map(function($v){return $v["acronym"];}, $arr)`. Then it is >=5.3. And if you write the function as normal function and pass the function name as string it it is > 5

Comment: Of course, there are many variants. I just to notify the question autor

Comment: @splash58 We live in 2105 so I hope I can assume, that everyone has at least PHP 5.5. Also if you think about, that this year should PHP 7 come out. Then I hope it won't take so long that everyone will use it.

Comment: For those who live in 2105 it is really not a problem :))))

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
$array = array(
    'mile'=>array('acronym'=>'mi'),
    'kilometer'=>array('acronym'=>'km')
    );

$acronym = 'km';

function get($each,$acronym)
{

    foreach($each as $k => $v)
    {
        if($v['acronym'] == $acronym)
        {
            return $k;
        }
    }
}

get($array,$acronym);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your array can have multiple levels, you can use a `stack`, and you recursively enumerate through the array, and when you encounter an `acronym` key, you have the full key path in the stack. Something like this:

```
function findAcronym($array, $keyStack, &$result) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        if($key === 'acronym') {
            $result[] = $keyStack;
        } elseif(is_array($value)) {
            $keyStack[] = $key;
            findAcronym($value, $keyStack, $result)
        }
    }
}
```

you can use the function like this:

```
$matches =[];
findAcronym($myArray, [], $matches);
```

`$matches` will be an array of array of keys, each array of keys corresponding to the key path that gets you to the `acronym` one.

As the function is recursive, it can go as deep as many levels the array has.